# How to get the signed the document uploaded to S3 in docusign using nodejs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to upload the signed document into s3 once its signed by all the signers using nodejs. I think the webhooks are the best to go with but can we actually get the signed document and upload it to s3 while using webhooks. Please suggest me the methods to retrieve the signed document and upload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the signed document bytes as part of the webhook call (DocuSign Connect) or you can make an eSignature API call to retrieve the document.

Here is an [article with code examples](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/) no how to do the latter.